# How to determine unknown parameters of a differential equation based on the best fit to a data set in Python?

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to fit different differential equations to a given data set with python. For this reason, I use the scipy package, respectively the solve_ivp function.
This works fine for me, as long as I have a rough estimate of the parameters (b= 0.005) included in the differential equations, e.g:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import numpy as np


def f(x, y, b):
    dydx= [-b[0] * y[0]]
    return dydx

xspan= np.linspace(1, 500, 25)
yinit= [5]
b= [0.005]


sol= solve_ivp(lambda x, y: f(x, y, b),
               [xspan[0], xspan[-1]], yinit, t_eval= xspan)

print(sol)
print("\n")

print(sol.t)
print(sol.y)

plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0], "b--")
```

However, what I like to achieve is, that the parameter b (or more parameters) is/are determined "automatically" based on the best fit of the solved differential equation to a given data set (x and y). Is there a way this can be done, for example by combining this example with the curve_fit function of scipy and how would this look?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, what you think about should work, it should be easy to plug together. You want to call

```
popt, pcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(curve, xdata, ydata, p0=[b0])
b = popt[0]
```

where you now have to define a function `curve(x,*p)` that transforms any list of point into a list of values according to the only parameter `b`.

```
def curve(x,b):
    res = solve_ivp(odefun, [1,500], [5], t_eval=x, args = [b])
    return res.y[0]
```

Add optional arguments for error tolerances as necessary.

---

To make this more realistic, make also the initial point a parameter. Then it also becomes more obvious where a list is expected and where single arguments. To get a proper fitting task add some random noise to the test data. Also make the fall to zero not so fast, so that the final plot still looks somewhat interesting.

```
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xmin,xmax = 1,500

def f(t, y, b):
    dydt= -b * y
    return dydt

def curve(t, b, y0):
    sol= solve_ivp(lambda t, y: f(t, y, b),
               [xmin, xmax], [y0], t_eval= t)
    return sol.y[0]


xdata = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, 25)
ydata = np.exp(-0.02*xdata)+0.02*np.random.randn(*xdata.shape)

y0 = 5
b= 0.005
p0 = [b,y0]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(curve, xdata, ydata, p0=p0)
b, y0 = popt

print(f"b={b}, y0 = {y0}")
```

This returns

```
b=0.019975693539459473, y0 = 0.9757709108115179
```

Now plot the test data against the fitted curve

[image]

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering! I tried to pick up your proposal and integrate it in my approach. However, as I am a beginner in Python it seems as I understood something wrong, respectively my changes produced an error (shown above).

Comment: One immediate error is that you left out the `return` statement in the `curve` function. Then you only should use one mechanism to pass additional parameters to the ODE function, either the `lambda` construct or the `args` optional argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time and giving me this great description, definitely learned something today!

Comment: I am sorry to bother you again, but how do I include another parameter n like in this equation (-b * n * t**(n-1)) * y to the to overall code. When doing this like in your example with y0 it causes an error "need at least one array to concatenate"?

Comment: Are you sure that what you pass are just scalars or flat tuples and arrays of scalars? Or is there still a missing return statement? Do you get an error when executing `ytest = curve(xdata, *p0)` after defining the sample data? Has `ytest` the same shape as `ydata`?

Comment: I had no problem inserting `n` into the parameter list, changing the ODE that way. Got results around `b=0.015, n=1.08, y0 = 1.00` with everything else unchanged.

Comment: Once again, a big thank you. It was a data type problem (caused by modifying the data set) as you suggested , fixed it and it now works perfectly!