# Capacitor discharge - solve differential equation with composite function

Tags: python, python-3.x, physics, differential-equations

I'm a python newbie. I tried to look for a solution to my problem on the web but I couldn't find any.
I want to solve a differential equation to find the capacitor voltage in time V(t) while it discharges through its own leakage current. The equation to solve is the following:

dV(t)/dt = I(V)/C, V(0) = V_init

Where I(V) is the leakage current which depends on the capacitor voltage V. I have: the leakage current as function of the voltage, the capacitance, the initial condition. The measured leakage current is interpolated to get a smooth function of V:

```
def fitfunc(V, B, D, E):
    return  B*(V**E)*exp(D*V)
coeff_fit, coeffcov = scipy.optimize.curve_fit(fitfunc, forced_voltage, measured_current, p0=[1e-8, 1, 1], maxfev=50000)

V = numpy.linspace(0, 4, 100001)
I = coeff_fit[0] * (V**coeff_fit[2]) * exp(coeff_fit[1] * V)
C = 1e-9
V_init = 1
```

I was looking at scipy.integrate.odeint but I don't know how to make it clear that the current is dependent on the voltage and not on the time.
Could you please help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems your function `I = I(V)` is given only as data, i.e. as a table of input values for `V` and output values for `I`. If that is that is the case, then maybe first you need to interpolate it, to get at least a continuous function `I = I(V)` and then solve the differential equation. Is this the case?

Comment: Thank you for your input, I'm now doing the interpolation and I can have as many points as I want for I(V). How would I proceed then?

Comment: What interpolation scheme are you using? Based on that, one could solve the equation exactly in the intervals between the measurements. alternatively, one can simply apply something like the solve_ivp function. But it is important that you include in your question your interpolation scheme, so that others can decide what to suggest.

Comment: I added it :) thank you!

Comment: Do you want to do something similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031381/how-to-determine-unknown-parameters-of-a-differential-equation-based-on-the-best, generally https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=+%5Bode%5D+curve_fit+answers%3A1? It should be easy to replace solve_ivp with odeint, even simplify the code a little.

Comment: Actually I don't want to do a fitting, I have no uknown parameter to fit, I just want to solve a differential equation where the current depends on the voltage, but the voltage is changing in time. Please see my own answer that I posted as a rough solution to the problem. Thank you for your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

[image: formula]

If you rearrange the equation a bit you can get

[image: formula]

Since C is a constant

[image: formula]

Which you can now Integrate

You can use `scipy.integrate` to get the RHS

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
#define your I as a function of V
def I(V):
    return V
res, err = quad(f, 0, 2) #limits of your V
```

or if you want to use the given data as an array use

```
import scipy
res = scipy.integrate.simps(I,V) #I and V are the arrays of measured data
```

Then you can use res to get V(t) and then set the initial value of V to get the constant.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But I think I wasn't clear in my explanation. The example I provided for V=numpy.linspace(0,2,100) is just the applied voltage at each leakage current point that I measure. Once I know how much leakage current I have for any applied voltage, then I charge up the capacitor to a certain voltage V_init and let it discharge by itself. I want to get how is the voltage decreasing in time.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to solve the differential equation "manually" in a for loop without making use of sophisticated functions and it turned out to be easier than I thought. Here is how I implemented it:

```
from numpy import asarray, argmin, linspace
from matplotlib.pyplot import semilogx, grid
def find_nearest(array, value):
    array = asarray(array)
    idx = (abs(array - value)).argmin()
    return idx

V_init = 1.0 # [V]
C = 1e-9 # [F]
max_time = 1e8
dt = 1000
time = linspace(0, max_time, int(max_time/dt))
V_t = [V_init]

for time_index, instant in enumerate(time):
    I_leak = I[find_nearest(V, V_t[time_index])]
    dV = -dt*I_leak/C
    V_t += [V_t[time_index] + dV]

semilogx(time, V_t[0:-1])
grid(True)
```

I'm still curious though if there is any cleaner solution to this problem. Please let me know if you have any ideas!

Comment: So essentially, `I_leak=scipy.interpolate.interp1d(V,I)` and `V_t=odeint(lambda vt,t:-I_leak(vt)/C, V_init, time)`.

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly and it's super fast! :) I'm curious to understand how that works: how does odeint know that "t" in the lambda and the last argument "time" are the same thing? How does it know that it's dV_t/dt and not dV_t/dvt?

Comment: The variables in the first argument are strictly local to that argument. The function is expected to be of format `f(x,t)` for an ODE `dx/dt=f(x(t),t)`. Not obeying this order gives errors or strange results. Note that all other scipy ODE integrators use the switched argument order `f(t,x)`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much!