# How to optimize a system of differential equations with curve_fit and solve_ivp?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, differential-equations

I want to optimize parameters in a system of differential equations. For a minimal example, I have the differential equations: 
 `dx1/dt=-k*x1` and 
 `dx2/dt=k*x1`.

Therefore, I use `solve_ivp` to integrate the ODE's and `curve_fit` to fit the parameters.

```
t_end=5
t_eval=np.linspace(0,t_end,t_end+1) #define timespan of 

def fun(t,x,k): #System of differential equations with parameter k to optimize
       return [-k*x[0],k*x[0]]

def fun2(t,k): #Solving differential equations and return x2(t)
       res=solve_ivp(fun, [0,t_end], [1,0],t_eval=t_eval,args=(k,))
       return res.y[1]

z=(1-np.exp(-0.2*t_eval))*np.ones(len(t_eval)) #creating an array with the analytic solution for the above statet differential equations with k=0.2
popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun2, t_eval, z)
```

This works, but if I increase `t_end` or make the differential equation more complicated, it always gets the same errors:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcasted together with shapes (xxx,) (xxx,)

e.g. with t_end=1200 i get the error

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcasted together with shapes (857,) (1201,)

or, with the slightly more complex system of ODE's and `t_end = 10`:

```
def fun(t,x,k1,k2): #System of differential equations
   return [-k1*x[0],k1*x[0]-k2*x[1],k2*x[1]]

def fun2(t,k1,k2): #Solving differential equations and return x3(t)
   res=solve_ivp(fun, [0,t_end], [1,0,0],t_eval=t_eval,args=(k1,k2))
   return res.y[2]
```

I get the below error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcasted together with shapes (8,) (11,)

I already figured out two options in `solve_ivp` which let me use higher `t_end`'s and more complex systems of ODE's: Choosing `method='DOP853'` or `method='LSODA'` with `min_step=1e-3` or `1e-2`.

But in the end, it's not enough for the System I want to use (4-5 differential equations with 7-8 parameters to fit and t_end of 6000+).

So, Is there any general problem with my approach or any trick I missed?

Comment: Does this example help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66031381/how-to-determine-unknown-parameters-of-a-differential-equation

Comment: Your observed problem is probably that the parameter k becomes negative and thus the x1 solution grows fast exponentially so that the solver bails out prematurely due to floating point overflow. Check the values of the parameter k and also res.status or res.message.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Lutz Lehmann, the ValueError rise due to floating point overflow. To avoid it, set the maximum bounds on the parameters "k". For 64 bit numbers, maximum possible number is approximately 10^308, so for exponential solutions we need to take the upper bound < 308/t_end and lower bound > -307/t_end:

```
t_end=6200
n=100
t_eval=np.linspace(0,t_end,n)
def fun(t,x,k1,k2):
   return [-k1*x[0],k1*x[0]-k2*x[1],k2*x[1]]
def fun2(t,k1,k2):
   res=solve_ivp(fun, [0,t_end], [1,0,0],t_eval=t_eval,args=(k1,k2))
   return res.y[2]

z=1-0.5*np.exp(-0.2*t_eval)-0.5*np.exp(-0.4*t_eval)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun2, t_eval, z,bounds=[(-307/t_end,-307/t_end),(308/t_end,308/t_end)])
res=solve_ivp(fun, [0,t_end], [1,0,0],t_eval=t_eval,args=(popt[0],popt[1]))

plt.plot(t_eval,res.y[2],'r', label="optimized data")
plt.plot(t_eval,z,'k--',label="data")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes thank you that was the point. With Lutz comment I printed k in fun2 and the error appeared when k got high negative numbers. So the negative numbers are the problem, so my bounds go from 1e-8 or something... Also because negative k's make no sense in my case :)